# multiple dropdowns related to one dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have a drop-down that contains the main groups, and I want the sub-groups of that group to be displayed in several drop-downs on the same page by selecting a main group, my selector is ID, my code is as follows Is

```
            IEnumerable<LessonsGroupViewModel> LessonGroupAndSubGroups = ViewBag.LessonGroup;
            <select name="ParentId" id="ParentId" class="form-select form-control">
                @foreach (var group in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(p => p.ParentId == null))
                {
                    <option value="@group.ID" name="@group.ID">@group.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>

            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>

var $select1 = $("#ParentId"),
    $select2 = $("#GroupId"),
    $options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function () {
    $select2.html($options.filter('[name="' + this.value + '"]'));
}).trigger('change');


enter code here
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do here. After the first select menu, are all of the other four select menus exactly the same?